# when i compile the QT project with armqmake in linux,the default argument for parameter 0 of...has not yet been parsed

Tags: c++, qt

its OK when i compile it on the windows(QT version 5.9.2,QT creater 4.4.4 , but the errors comes out when i compile it on Linux with Arm-qmake(arm-qt5.5).

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:49:12: error: the default argument for parameter 0 of 
'Camera::Camera(QWidget*)' has not yet been parsed
Makefile:1292: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

and my main.cpp is following

```
#include "camera.h"
#include <QtWidgets>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Camera camera;
    camera.show();
    return app.exec();
};
```

//and  the class camera
//camera.h

```
class Camera : public QMainWindow{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Camera(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Camera();
private:
    Ui::Camera *ui;
}
```

//camera.cpp

```
Camera::Camera(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent),ui(new Ui::Camera)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

Comment: Where is ui defined?

Comment: #ifndef CAMERA_H
#define CAMERA_H

#include <QCamera>
#include <QCameraImageCapture>
#include <QMediaRecorder>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "date_weather.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Camera; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Camera : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Camera(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Camera();

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47214472/edit) and add it there.

Comment: i declare it in camera.h ,and setup in camera.cpp.

Comment: defined it below a folder :forms

Comment: What version of Qt do you have and what is the compiler that you use?

Comment: Qt code is not written in **C** so please stop spamming irrelevant tags!

Comment: So sorry about that, i just thought that linux is relative to c.